# SSIS Accessing MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, ssis

I created the MySQL connection in the SSIS, it connects properly.
Then created a data flow for tables copying. MySQL -> SQL
Set an ADO.Net Source and a OLE DB destination.

Inside the ADO.Net Source, I select Table Or View and it goes OK, I can view all the tables, they are listed. I select the one desired to be copied and when I press "preview" the error pops up.

[image]

Comment: Problem Solved. Restarted client, recreated MySQL Connection inside SSIS and it worked. Strange since the data is the same, but now it works.

Answer (score 2):

I thik you have a problem on your MySQL syntax.

Try this link  to configure [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-mode.html) to run in ANSI mode

Comment: Please Diego, correct me if I'm wrong. But I don't have any MySQL sintax, I'm just selecting the source tables to be copied. The only strings I have are the Connection ones. 'ConnectionString'.

Comment: Should I build an expression?

Comment: try changing it to "SQL" and type SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'ANSI'; before your statement.

Comment: can you try following the link I sent you and change the configuration on MySQl?

Comment: I have no permission to do that, but will ask for it. Thanks a lot.